# How to remove old git entries from a private remote repository?

Tags: git

I have a remote private git repository and the server hard drive is getting full. In fact, I just tried pushing some changes and the remote server from my development machine, and the remote server has run out of space.

I have a development machine with a local repository that pushes changes to the remote. I also have a development laptop that pulls and pushes to the remote, and a production  machine that pulls from the remote.

Since I am the only developer, I really don't think I need to keep all the git pushes to the remote repository. What is the best way to remove a lot of the old pushes (say everything up to the start of 2020) so I can free up some space on the remote server? I still need to make sure that my development machine can pull the latest changes as well as my development laptop. How will erasing all the old pushes to the remote repository impact the local repositories on my development machine, laptop, and production machine? I assume some synchronization will be needed.

Thanks!

Mark

Comment: Removing commits is re-writing history, so you'd probably have to re-clone all your repos.  Also, unless you're pushing large files on a regular basis, then cleaning up your git repos probably isn't going to gain you much disk space.

Comment: The remote repository is 2.1 GB, and one project is 1.4 GB alone.

Answer (score 0):

This solution solves my root problem of running out of space on my hard drive, but it does not address how to remove old commits. There seem to be many ways to remove old commits, but I was too chicken to try them.

I used rsync to move the entire git repository to another partition on another disk, then deleted the original git repository. I then created a sym link to the copied repository on the original disk so none of the clients had to change anything. I was able to free up needed disk space on the original disk, and not loose any of my commits. Yeah!